# How to exclude a package while compiling WebAssembly

Tags: go, refactoring, webassembly, go-modules

I am trying to compile some small Go application to WebAssembly using this command:
`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build .`
My small app uses some function from 3rd party package that has dependency to `golang.org/x/sys/unix` that is not supposed to be complied for Web Assembly.
Even if my application does not use any functions from `golang.org/x/sys/unix`, I can not compile my code to WASM due to error:

`imports golang.org/x/sys/unix: build constraints exclude all Go files in /some_path/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix`

**Are there any workarounds?**

I tried to refactor the code to extract the functions that I need to another package without dependency to `golang.org/x/sys/unix` but it's not the easiest thing in this project.

Answer (score 0):

[Build tags](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool) can exclude tagged files from being compiled. Have not tested this specific tag, but something like this should work:

```
// +build !JS

package <snip>
```

Comment: yes, sys/unix package contains conditions that do not allow to compile webassembly. My question was how to say to the compile to ignore this dependency .... because it won't be used in webAssembly....